# Procyon vs CFR for Java Decompiler

Tags: decompilation

I'm trying to find the best Java class decompiler thats the most reliable. What's the difference between Procyon and CFR as far as decompiling the most classes sucessfully?

Comment: Opinion based questions are not a good fit for this site. Try to rephrase it to something that has an unambiguous answer.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Why is this question bad? Give me an example.